# jQuery - find multiple associated classes using the last digit of the class?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
            <fieldset>
                <legend><span>Contact Details</span> <span class="edit1">Edit</span><span class="hide1">Hide</span></legend>
                <div>
                <!--content-->
                </div>
            </fieldset>


            <fieldset>
                <legend><span>Contact Details</span> <span class="edit2">Edit</span><span class="hide2">Hide</span></legend>
                <div>
                <!--content-->
                </div>
            </fieldset>
```

The spans with the class "hide1" and "hide2" are set to display:none on page load.

Within this code, using jQuery, I am trying to do the following:

- if edit1 is clicked on, this span becomes hidden, and the associated span with the class "hide1" becomes visible.
- This should be the same for all other spans in the code e.g. edit2 and hide2. Also if I want to add further edit and hide classes, the function should be able to handle this too e.g. edit3 and hide3 and so on.

So far, I have been able to find the edit span that is clicked on and hide it. I am struggling to get the associated "hide" class. Can anyone help me do this please? Here is my jQuery function so far:

```
        var spans = $("#myIntForm").find("span[class^='edit'],span[class^='hide']");

        spans.click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            spans.filter("span[class^='hide']").hide();
            if($this.attr('class').substr(0,4)=='edit')
                {
                    var visible = $this.filter("span[class^='"+$this.attr('class').substr(0,4)+"']");
                    visible.hide();

                    //find the class 'hide' with same ending number as class 'edit' and display it.
                    var invisible;
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar before, it was easier for me to delimit the classname in some way - i.e an underscore, and also using an ID to help with selecting like so:

```
<span class='edit' id='edit_1'>Edit 1</span>
<span class='hide' id='hide_1'>Hide 1</span>
```

Then you can find the associated classes like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.hide').hide();
  $('.edit').click(function(){
    //each time an edit class is clicked, show its associated hide div
    var aNum = $(this).attr('id');
    //get the number at the end of the ID of this particular edit div           
    aNum=(aNum.substring(aNum.indexOf('_')+1, aNum.length));

    //select and show the associated hide_1 div
    $('#hide_'+aNum).show();

    //hide $(this)
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

I haven't tested this but you get the idea.
One other point is that I think you don't need to assign $(this) to a var, I don't see anything in your code that would warrant that.

Hope this helps

EDIT: Forgot to hide the edit div on click, code updated

2nd EDIT: Woops, missed a close bracket, also needed a +1 on the substring :) works fine now - got an example up here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rYMtq/

A bit irrelevant now that you got an answer but an unclosed bracket is enough to keep me awake at night :D

Comment: this seemed to only display the very last "hide" span in the code.

Answer (score 2):

I've gone ahead and changed a bit of your jQuery code. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aPERV/1/) with a working example. Hope it helps.

```
var $spans =$("#myIntForm").find("span[class^='edit'],span[class^='hide']");

$spans.click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $hideSpan = $this.siblings('span[class^="hide"]'),
        $editSpan = $this.siblings('span[class^="edit"]');

    $this.toggle();
    $hideSpan.toggle();
    $editSpan.toggle();

});
```